# Is there an easy way to see how many NFT's exist on the Cardano blockchain?

Tags: native-assets

I would like to get the number of all NFT's ever created on Cardano. This means all native assets with a supply of 1. Is there a website where I can find this information or are there tools that can achieve this?

I don't mind running my own node for this, if there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://pool.pm/tokens which seems to provide the total at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can fetch them all from blockFrost with this end point

https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets

For a detailed explanation here is the Link

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/~1assets/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets/get)